# Responsive Wordress Site - Serve different post types to each device

Tags: multisite, responsive

I currently run a multisite wordpress website. for example:

**wwww.domain.com**

**www.domain.com/mobile**

**www.domain.com/tablet**

With a separate WP install on each sub domain. I would like to optimise things by creating one responsive site. However my problem is that the content for each device is different.

So my question is, how do I serve different content to a device from one wordpress install? is there a way of utilising custom post types or similar?

Comment: There is no way you going to achieve this using Wordpress. The closest you are going to come with wordpress is `wp_is_mobile()` which can detect mobile phones. It has to be noted, this function is very unreliable. My opinions, use responsive design with media queries

Comment: am looking into mobile detect now. Media queries could work but with the amount of different content there would be a lot of hidden content, I would prefer only the required content is served for each device

Comment: Different content based on user device? It doesn't sound good to me and may not for search engines. Your title is confusing: responsive website - Serve different post types; a responsive website serve the same content, the design adapt to device screen and this is the way to go nowdays.

Comment: no so much different content but different posts.

It is a marketing website which show offers for products, some are not on a specific device and if they are the product offers is different

Comment: ... For marketing it can make sense....

Comment: it's just trying to find a method. having a multisite set up is very tedious to maintain.